# How to Sort ListBox in descending order on data-binding mode?

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox

How to Sort ListBox in descending order on data-binding mode?

I give an example:

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument printDoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
ArrayList paperSizes = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count; i++)
{
   paperSizes.Add(printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[i]);
}

listBox1.DataSource = paperSizes;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "PaperName";
listBox1.ValueMember = "Kind";
```

Answer (score 1):

use **paperSizes.sort(paperSizes );**

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument printDoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
ArrayList paperSizes = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count; i++)
{
   paperSizes.Add(printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[i]);
}
paperSizes.sort();
listBox1.DataSource = paperSizes;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "PaperName";
listBox1.ValueMember = "Kind";
```

Comment: What is Collections.sort(paperSizes )? I need to sort in descending order. I got error say {"Failed to compare two elements in the array."} when call paperSizes.Sort();.

Comment: You need to get Kind of Papersize before to sort:  printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[i].Kind.ToString()

Comment: If I just load Kind, the ArrayList can be sorted and ListBox also can be sorted.I know it. But my question is how to sort ListBox on Data-Binding mode.

Comment: The above code give error say {"Failed to compare two elements in the array."}.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
private void SortListBoxItems(ref ListBox lb)
{
    List<object> items;
    items = lb.Items.OfType<object>().ToList();
    lb.Items.Clear();
    lb.Items.AddRange(items.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Raise an error "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set."

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got constructive answer and graceful solution yet. But with Rai and NicoRiff's help, I realize that we can't do more on Data-Binding mode, probably, I should do sorting before data-binding. Another thing I gained is that I should put Try and Catch to avoid silent crash and provide errors information in case accidentally call ListBox.Sorted =true or ListBox.Items.Add method on data-binding mode.

```
1. In Rai's code sample, when we call paperSizes.sort(), VS catch error "Failed to compare two elements in the array."
2. in Nico's code sample, because ListBox is on data-binding mode, VS will raise an error "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set."
```